# C memory allocation in student structure not working

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, function-pointers, dynamic-programming

I have to implement these functions in **internal.h** below:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_INTERNAL_H
#define STUDENT_INTERNAL_H

#include "student.h"

/** Allocate memory for a new @ref student object. */
struct student *student_alloc(void);

/*** Initialize an already-allocated @ref student object.
* @returns   NULL on failure but does not free the memory
*/

struct student *student_init(struct student *, const char *name, size_t namelen, 
                             struct student_id, student_complete);

#endif /* STUDENT_INTERNAL_H */
```

This is what I have so far but I am confused and it's not working:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "student.h"
#include "transcript.h"
#include "internal.h"

/**
* Initialize an already-allocated @ref student object.
* @returns   NULL on failure but does not free the memory
*/
struct student *student_init(struct student *student, const char *name, size_t namelen,
                             struct student_id stud_id, student_complete stud_complete) {

    struct student *initialized_student;

    name = malloc(sizeof(namelen));
    initialized_student = malloc(sizeof (student));

    if (student_alloc()) {
        initialized_student->s_name = name;
        initialized_student->s_id = stud_id;
        initialized_student->s_complete = stud_complete;

        return initialized_student;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`stud_complete` here is a function pointer which is declared in a deferent header file **student.h** like `typedef int (*student_complete)(struct student *);`

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: `initialized_student = malloc(sizeof (student));`is wrong -->> `initialized_student = malloc(sizeof (struct student));` or even better : `initialized_student = malloc(sizeof *initialized_sudent);` and `name = malloc(sizeof(namelen));`is also wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is confusing:

What is `namelen` ?

- is it the length of the initial prefix of `name` that is the name of the student?  In this case you should allocate one extra byte for the null terminator and copy the name appropriately.
- is it the maximum length for the student name?  Again if this a the length, not the size, you need an extra byte for the null terminator.
- in any case `sizeof(namelen)` is inappropriate.

What does `student_alloc()` do?

Similarly, the size passed to `malloc()` to allocate the `student` structure should be that of `struct student` or more reliably that of the type pointed to by the destination pointer.

Here is a corrected version:

```
struct student *student_init(struct student *student, const char *name, size_t namelen,
                             struct student_id stud_id, student_complete stud_complete) {

    struct student *initialized_student = malloc(sizeof(*initialized_student));
    char *s_name = calloc(namelen + 1);

    if (initialized_student && s_name && student_alloc()) {
        strncat(s_name, name, namelen);
        initialized_student->s_name = s_name;
        initialized_student->s_id = stud_id;
        initialized_student->s_complete = stud_complete;
        return initialized_student;
    } else {
        free(initialized_student);
        free(s_name);
        return 0;
    }
}
```